# Align text to right in the left align paragraph in React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

[image]

**In React native**
I want to make ui like above but get confused how to align Date to end when paragraph ends in react native. This is what I am trying so far.

```
<Text> Long para end <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>9:21</Text> </Text>
```

Comment: Here's something that [does the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u1zrhqbo/). You need to make sure the `::after` is equal in size as the absolutely positioned element. Typically by giving them the same content and font size, but you could hard-code it, if you don't need a dynamic solution. A much simpler solution is to have `9:21` on the next line, with `float: right`.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The linked question deals only with web CSS and won't work for React Native - maybe the OP didn't mean to tag this with reactjs. The code snippet contains <Text> tags, which are only in React Native.

Comment: Thanks @Abe voting for reopen the question